# How does strtok actually take each word?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I have a problem in C++ that requests me to split a phrase in words and show each word in a line.

The phrase is taken from a file `phrase.in` and put in a char vector `phrs[256]`

Now, the problem is here :

```
p = strtok(aux, " ");

while(p)
{
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    cout << p;
}
```

When I'm trying to split the phrase "RAM memory is important", it only shows me

```
memory
is
important
```

What can I do to make the program to show me the first word ?

Comment: Yes, I copied from phrs[256] into aux[256] to keep the original phrase

Comment: This looks like homework, so the use of `strtok` is probably okay, but in general, you better avoid it in production code. That is not a thread safe function.

Comment: Don't use `strtok`. Convert your char vector into a `std::string` and tokenise it then.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, the first `strtok` call returns a pointer to the beginning of the string, where the string `"RAM"` is at. The next call makes `p` point to the next word, skipping `"RAM"`.

To fix that, just exchange the two lines in the `while`-loop:

```
while(p)
{
    cout << p;
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still a newbie in C++, so I still need to learn about these things. I'll keep in mind this. :)

Comment: @itmushroom, the only thing to keep in mind is that you should read the documentation of API you use.

Comment: @itmushroom If your question has been answered, please accept the best answer to reward the creator and mark the problem as solved.